# How to Get Unique Product URL Key Magento2?

Tags: magento2, product, url

I making a commerce product with the help of Magento and I am new to this, my question is while adding a product from Magento admin, it stores the search engine optimization URL key default as the name of the product but I want to extend its functionality so that it can store unique URL key.

for example:

product name: Iphone 6s 32GB

By default Magento generate URL key : iphone-6s-32GB.html

but I want to store the url key with product id,so `url key` would be always unique

It should be generate Url Key: **iphone-6s-32GB-{productid}.html**

Comment: let me know exact what u require could u explain me thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using controller di following in your constructor

```
public function __construct(
   \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
) {
  $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}
```

and use following to get urlkey in execute function assuming you have a product id of the product whose urlkey you want

```
public function execute(){
      $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($productId);
      $urlkey = $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By Default Magento2 uses the product name to generate the url and there is no direct way to check if URL key exist or get Unique URL key.

If you check `Product Import` Class function, you can check function `checkUrlKeyDuplicates`, how magento check URL key existence.

`Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product`

I have taken the same approach and create product Unique URl. You can found whole explanantion in my answer on the below question:

[Magento 2: How to generate Product URL Key when creating Product from Rest API?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180517/magento-2-how-to-generate-product-url-key-when-creating-product-from-rest-api)