# Update product visibility to search only programmaticallly. $product->setVisibility(3) does not work, break the script

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, programmatically, visibility

I have this script to update product attributes, everything else run fine until i added this line below of code to update visibility to search only.
I know i can update it through catalog product grid, but would like to know why this doesn't work.

```
->setVisibility(3)
```

or

```
->setVisibility(search_only)
```

or

```
->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH)
```

more details:

```
 /*check url key*/

 /*holder for new url key in case it's a duplicate*/
//$name = $product->getName();
//$url = preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $name);
//$url = strtolower($url) . 'discontinued';
$currentURL = $product->getUrlKey();
$urlKey = $currentURL;
$storeId = 1;
//echo $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId() . '<br />'; //here returned 1
    $isUrlDuplicate;
    $urlKey .= '.html';
    $connection = $resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $tablename = $connection->getTableName('url_rewrite');
    $sql = $connection->select()->from(
                    ['url_rewrite' => $connection->getTableName('url_rewrite')], ['request_path', 'store_id']
            )->joinLeft(
                    ['cpe' => $connection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity')], "cpe.entity_id = url_rewrite.entity_id"
            )->where('request_path IN (?)', $urlKey)
            ->where('store_id IN (?)', $storeId)
            ->where('cpe.sku not in (?)', $sku);
    $urlKeyDuplicates = $connection->fetchAssoc($sql);
    if (!empty($urlKeyDuplicates)) {
    //  return false;
        $isUrlDuplicate = 0;
    } else {
        //return true;
        $isUrlDuplicate = 1;
        //if is duplicate, add eol to url
        $newURL = $currentURL . '-eol';
        $product->setStoreId(1)->setUrlKey($newURL);
        echo 'setting new url key to ' . $newURL  .'<br />';
    }
echo 'original url key is '.$currentURL . ' is duplicate? ' . ( $isUrlDuplicate > 0 ? 'yes' : 'no') .'<br />';

//$price = trim($data['price']);
echo 'Getting product SKU: '.$sku.', with EOL Status: '.$product->getIsEol().'<br />'; 
echo 'Updating product SKU: '.$sku.', with EOL Status: '.$status.'('.$option_id.')'.'<br />'; // .' and Price:'.$price.'<br />';
$product->setIsEol($option_id)   // use option_id here
->setStoreId(1) // this is needed because if you have multiple store views, each individual store view will get "Use default value" unchecked for multiple attributes - which causes issues.
->setCustomStockStatus($status_id)
->setMetaDescription('Discontinued')
->setVisibility(3)   //this line break the script  //VISIBILITY_IN_SEARCH VISIBILITY_IN_CATALOG VISIBILITY_BOTH
//->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
->save();
```

error_log

```
[07-Jun-2019 00:12:42 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'digital-to-analog-audio-converter.html-1' for key 'URL_REWRITE_REQUEST_PATH_STORE_ID' in /home/mystore/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mystore/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/mystore/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(93): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/mystore/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(303): Magento\Framework\DB\Statement\Pdo\Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/mystore/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/mystore/public_html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT  INTO `u...', Array)
#5 /home/mystore/public_h in /home/mystore/public_html/vendor/magento/module-url-rewrite/Model/Storage/DbStorage.php on line 220
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the `->setVisibility(3)` call itself but the creation of an url rewrite entry for that product which is associated with the changing of the visibility. Most likely the product was `'Not Visible Individually'`  before and had no entry in `url_rewrite` table.

If you change the `url_key` for that product to something unique, the saving operation would work.

To check if a value used for `url_key` is unique you can use a method like posted in this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/181898/76597

I would suggest to implement such a check in your code.

Comment: Hi, the original visibility is set to catalog/search, and status is set to disabled. I found another enabled product with the same url key. I added the duplicate check in my script, but when seems like ->setUrlkey( $cuurentURL . 'eol') does not save. can you check my updated code? thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but your conflict is in store 1 and you check for existing rewrites in store 0. Do you enter the else path in the duplicate check?

Comment: i'm a little confusion about the store ids ( since i only have one store). when i getStoreID(), it returned 1. i updated the scripts. Yes, i did enter the into the else path.

Comment: this seems to be the issue i am having with magento 2.2.6, i applied the code from here and seems to able to save the products now. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7298#issuecomment-463532802